# error al migrar table en Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

- Estoy intentando migrar las tablas que vienen por defecto en el proyecto de Laravel a mi base de datos,  pero tengo el problema que adjunto en la fotografía, estoy utilizando  una maquina virtual   de Ubuntu, la base de datos la he creado con phpmyadmin, no se si tendrá algo que ver.. es como si no la pudiera detecta de que existe

  [image: Texto]

Comment: Hola. Algunas instalaciones de Laravel (ej. Bitnami LampStack) son autocontenido (relativamente independientes) y tanto su php como MySql no son los mismos que puedan estar instalados globalmente. Ese podría ser tu caso. Te sugiero entrar a phpMyAdmin y usar su opción de exportar como archivo .sql y luego importar el archivo a la BD a la que quieres migrar.

Comment: Pero son archivos PHP, como hago para exportar eso ?

Comment: Busca en tu instalación de PHP en el archivo `php.ini` si tienes descomentado la opcion del driver pdo Mysql si tiene un `;` quitalo para descomentar.